# How To Get User Video From YouTube In A Paginated Way

Tags: php, http, video, youtube, pagination

I am trying to get my channel videos which I have almost archived, However YouTube retrieves 50 results per page and my channel has 150 videos and it will be neater to paginate results. is it possible to do this with the below code? if so please do show me how

I am a PHP programmer but completely new to using it and sending http requests to you tube including paginating things.

Here's what I have so far

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$feedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/gamertv273/uploads?start-index=1&max-results=10';
$sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
$i=0;
foreach ($sxml->entry as $entry) {
      $media = $entry->children('media', true);
      $watch = (string)$media->group->player->attributes()->url;
      $thumbnail = (string)$media->group->thumbnail[0]->attributes()->url;

      ?>

<link rel='previous' type='application/atom+xml'
  href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/gamertv273/uploads?start-index=1&max-results=10'/>
<link rel='next' type='application/atom+xml'
  href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/gamertv273/uploads?start-index=2&max-results=10'/>
      <div class="videoitem">
        <div class="videothumb"><a href="<?php echo $watch; ?>" class="watchvideo"><img src="<?php echo $thumbnail;?>"
        alt="<?php echo $media->group->title; ?>" /></a></div>


        <div class="videotitle">
            <h3><a href="<?php echo $watch; ?>" class="watchvideo"><?php echo $media->group->title; ?></a></h3>

        </div>
      </div>      
<?php $i++; if($i==3) { echo '<div class="clear small_v_margin"></div>'; $i=0; } } ?>
```

Comment: Manage to get something basic that works I see what you can all come up with to help the communnity out ;)

Comment: What is your question? If you want to try if it works try to execute it ;-) If the output is not what you expected get back here we can try to search for a specific issue. But generally your idea is correct.

Comment: I don't have a full on pagination and I think it's hard to implement one without the use of the you tube API which you need to learn but my idea is a papgination where you click More Videos.. but it will do ;)

Answer (score 0):

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/gamertv273/uploads?start-index=100&max-results=50

*start-index* is the index of the video to start with.

*max-results* is how many entries are returned (max allowed is 50).

**STEP 1**

Firt I suggest you parse a **page number** into your own page and then your code queries YTube accordingly. i.e.

www.yourwebsite.com/your-page.php?**page=1**

And in your code:

```
<?php

$results_per_page = 20;
$start_index = $_GET['page'] - 1 * ($results_per_page + 1);
$feedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/gamertv273/uploads?start-index=' . $start_index . '&max-results=' . $results_per_page;
//[rest of the code]

?>
```

This will return results 0-20 if your page is 1, 20-40 if you page is 2 etc.

**STEP 2**

Then, you need to put page numbers. If you have 126 videos, then there should be 7 pages available with 20 results each. To know how many videos in total, refer to the API below:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/gamertv273/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=0
```

You can now parse the json response using json_decode(), get **totalItems** and divide by $results_per_page to get how many pages are available. Then, easy to print  tags for each page, with previous/next buttons.

```
<a href="www.yourwebsite.com/your-page.php?page=1">previous page</a>
<a href="www.yourwebsite.com/your-page.php?page=3">next page</a>
<a href="www.yourwebsite.com/your-page.php?page=1">page 1</a>
<a href="www.yourwebsite.com/your-page.php?page=2">page 2</a>
<a href="www.yourwebsite.com/your-page.php?page=3">page 3</a>
<a href="www.yourwebsite.com/your-page.php?page=4">page 4</a>
```

Comment: the link does not work anymore